# calculate the progress of loading web page on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, progress-bar

I want to display the progress of loading web page. I use BrowserFieldListener to calculate progress in web page. But nothing display in the screen. How can I calculate the percent of this progress?

class BrowserFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{

```
public BrowserFieldDemoScreen()
{
    BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig
.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);


    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();



   browserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
   browserField.addListener(new BrowserFieldListener() {

    public void documentAborted(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (document != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            String url = document.getBaseURI();
            browserField.getErrorHandler().displayContentError(url, "Aborted loading document '" + title + "'");
        }
        super.documentAborted(browserField, document);
    }


    public void documentCreated(BrowserField browserField, ScriptEngine scriptEngine, Document document) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (document != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            String url = document.getBaseURI();
            System.out.println("[" + this.getClass().getName() + "] Document '" + title + "' created for URL " + url);
        }
        super.documentCreated(browserField, scriptEngine, document);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param browserField - The BrowserField to which the document belongs
         * @param document - The document for which this event belongs.
     */
    public void documentError(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (document != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            String url = document.getBaseURI();
            browserField.getErrorHandler().displayContentError(url, "Error loading document '" + title + "'");
        }
        super.documentError(browserField, document);
    }


    public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (document != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            System.out.println("[" + this.getClass().getName() + "] Document '" + title + "' loaded");
        }
        super.documentLoaded(browserField, document);
    }


    public void documentUnloading(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (document != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            System.out.println("[" + this.getClass().getName() + "] Document '" + title + "' unloading");
        }
        super.documentUnloading(browserField, document);
    }


    public void downloadProgress(BrowserField browserField, ContentReadEvent event) throws Exception
    {
        if ((browserField != null) && (event != null))
        {
            String title = browserField.getDocumentTitle();
            double amtComplete = event.getItemsRead() / event.getItemsToRead();
            System.out.println("[" + this.getClass().getName() + "] Document '" + title + "' loading " + String.valueOf(amtComplete) + "% complete");
        }
        super.downloadProgress(browserField, event);
    }});


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the percentage of a web page that is currently loaded in a BrowserField you should attach a [BrowserFieldListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldListener.html) to your BrowserField.

The event in particular you will be interested in is the `downloadProgress(BrowserField browserField,                    ContentReadEvent event)`.

Here is a great tutorial from the official Blackberry support forums that will teach you to do exactly what you want: [BrowserField Sample Code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldListener-class/ta-p/496213).

Comment: The sample code only prints the current progress to the console. You will need to rewrite the `downloadProgress` method to update a progress bar.

I have found an example for you on the Blackberry Support forums [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-track-progress-of-page-loads-in-your-BrowserField2/ta-p/617436).

Comment: I see this link when I try it the web page didn't displayed and the progress is 0 all the time when I click enter